# dust file causing Maximum call stack size error in node.js web app

Tags: node.js, dust.js

I am facing this peculiar issue wherein after a dust template file exceeds a certain amount of text, i get the Maximum Call Stack size error in node.js console. However, as a quick fix, when I break up the dust.js file into 2 files or add more nesting of dust partials and reduce some amount of content in the original file, the error disappears and the web app works fine and renders the template successfully. The amount of text after which node.js gives the error and crashes the app is different for different dust files. Has anyone faced this kind of issue before and know the root cause of the problem?

Comment: Can you share the code in the breaking template?